Azure Devops Pipeline - How to set env variable based on variable set in previous task
I want to have such flow
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: "Export Service Principal credentials"
    inputs:
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      connectedServiceNameARM: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
      addSpnToEnvironment: true
      inlineScript:
        if [[ -n "$idToken" ]]; then
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_OIDC_TOKEN;issecret=true]${idToken}"
        fi

        if [[ -n "$servicePrincipalKey" ]]; then
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET;issecret=true]${servicePrincipalKey}"
        fi

and then use them, based if they were actually exported or not. But it does not work:
  - bash: |
      echo $TEST_OIDC # $[variables.ARM_OIDC_TOKEN]
      echo $TEST_SECRET # $[variables.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET]
    env:
      TEST_OIDC: $[variables.ARM_OIDC_TOKEN]
      TEST_SECRET: $[variables.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET]

I already tried with macro expressions, but because only one of those 2 variables would be set, Azure Devops leaves the other one as string.
  - bash: |
      echo $TEST_OIDC # ***
      echo $TEST_SECRET # $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)
    env:
      TEST_OIDC: $(ARM_OIDC_TOKEN)
      TEST_SECRET: $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)

And I need to provide some stupid workarounds, just to make it work:
  - bash: |
      if [[ -n "$TEST_OIDC" && "$TEST_OIDC != '$(''ARM_OIDC_TOKEN) ]]; then # '$('' to skip variable expansion
        echo $TEST_OIDC # ***
      fi 
      [[ -n "$TEST_SECRET" && "$TEST_SECRET != '$(''ARM_CLIENT_SECRET) ]]; then # '$('' to skip variable expansion
        echo $TEST_SECRET # print nothing as expected
      fi
    env:
      TEST_OIDC: $(ARM_OIDC_TOKEN)
      TEST_SECRET: $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)


Glad to see you in stack overflow.  As per your requirement, you can predefine the variable with empty value, or with a trick to continueonerror with setting non-secret variable to help set env. Please check the details below, thanks.

It appears you are defining different type service connection as parameter in AzureCLI@2 task, and would like to set the env accordingly.
You can predefine the two variables with empty value, if it's not overriden by logging command(echo "##vso[task.setvariable...), it will display nothing instead of $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET) in this case.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
  - name: serviceConnection
    default: ARMConn4

variables:
  - name: ARM_OIDC_TOKEN         # predefine the variables value
    value: ''
  - name: ARM_CLIENT_SECRET
    value: ''
  

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: "Export Service Principal credentials"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      if [[ -n "$idToken" ]]; then
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_OIDC_TOKEN;issecret=true]${idToken}"
      fi
      
      if [[ -n "$servicePrincipalKey" ]]; then
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET;issecret=true]${servicePrincipalKey}"
      fi
    addSpnToEnvironment: true


- bash: |
    echo $TEST_OIDC 
    echo $TEST_SECRET
  env:
    TEST_OIDC: $(ARM_OIDC_TOKEN)
    TEST_SECRET: $(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)

The output:

Another option: Sine non-secret variable will be automatically mapped into environment, you can use one more logging command(echo "##vso[task.setvariable...) to set the variable, add continueOnError: true to ignore the error.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

parameters:
  - name: serviceConnection
    default: ARMConn4

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: "Export Service Principal credentials"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      if [[ -n "$idToken" ]]; then
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_OIDC_TOKEN;issecret=true]${idToken}"
      fi
      
      if [[ -n "$servicePrincipalKey" ]]; then
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET;issecret=true]${servicePrincipalKey}"
      fi
    addSpnToEnvironment: true


- script: |
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TEST_OIDC]$(ARM_OIDC_TOKEN)"
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TEST_SECRET]$(ARM_CLIENT_SECRET)"
  continueOnError: true


- bash: |
    echo $TEST_OIDC # check the value
    echo $TEST_SECRET # check the value

In this case, it will only set the environment which is available, which can achieve the same.



I'm not a fan of the second solution, since it would just globally unpack a secret for everyone, but the first one was a clever usage of prepopulated variables. Thanks!
